# SQL IF statement not working - unrecognised statement

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I'm trying to set up a database that logs search terms. For each search term entered SQL checks if the search term exists, if not it INSERTS a new record, if true it UPDATES the existing field

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM searchmetrics WHERE keyword = 'keyword'))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO searchmetrics(id, name, metric)
    VALUES('', 'keyword', '1')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    UPDATE searchmetrics
    SET metrics = metrics + 1
    WHERE name = 'keyword'
END
```

I'm getting following error:

> Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF" at position 0)
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

I've double-checked the syntax and it looks correct to me, the IF statement is also highlighted red in the SQL console but seems to be the only thing that is. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You miss `)`  check it

Comment: Apologies that was an error pasting the code here, I've updated it and the error remains the same

Comment: This looks more like T-SQL (MS SQL Server) syntax to me. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/if-statement/ check documentation for IF syntax?

Comment: Are you attempting to write a stored procedure?

Comment: Is column 'id' an identity column? If so, you cannot insert anything to the identity column because this is a system generated key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MariaDB, `IF` and `IF()` have different semantics. It seems you wanted to use `IF` when you actually used `IF()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `IF` statement must be inside a Stored Routine.  If it is not, it cannot be made to work.

If it is in a SP, please provide the Routine declaration, including `DELIMITER` statements.